# Looking for an online translation community open to collaborators

Tags: localization, translation

I'm searching for an online translation community where anyone can collaborate.

Specifically, I'm interested in translations for an app and would like to engage with native speakers of the target language.

I remember a few years ago that I was involved in one of these platforms, but I no longer recall the name or the website link.

Can someone suggest any links ?

Thank you!